# Calcular valores acima da media e abaixo de 7 em uma lista Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista

```
lista =[]
val = int(input ("digite o valor: ")) 
while (val != -1):
  lista.append (val)
  val = int (input ("digite o valor: "))
print ('a lista: ', lista)

print('a quantidade de valores informados é: ')
print(len(lista)) # quantidade de valores informados

print('a ordem informada foi: ', lista)
lista.reverse()
print('em ordem inversa:')

for x in zip(lista):
    print(x)
    
soma = sum(lista)
print('a soma dos valores é: ', soma)

media = soma / len(lista)

print('a media é: ', media)
```

Após fazer até o `print('a media é: ',media)` eu preciso calcular a quantidade de valores acima da média (dado os numeros aleatorios que posso inserir na lista)

E também a quantidade de valores que estão abaixo de 7 (dado os numeros abaixos de 7 que posso inserir na lista)

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Faça um loop em todos os valores da sua lista e aplique uma condicional se os valores estão acima da média e outra para caso estejam a baixo de  7 `if nota > media : #Do stuff else if nota < 7 : #do Other sutff else : # Do Stuff`

Answer (score 1):

### Solução

Para você obter tanto a quantidade de valores acima da média e quantidade de valores que estão abaixo de 7 vai ser necessário utilizar uma estrutura de condição (if-elif-else) do Python.

### Etapas

1. Para obter esses resultados eu utilizei duas variáveis sendo elas `acima` que vai ficar responsável de armazenar a quantidade de valores que estão acima da média e a variável `baixo`que vai ficar responsável de armazenar a quantidade de valores que estão abaixo de 7.
2. Após ter essas variáveis, eu utilizei a função `for`para percorrer a lista e utilizei a estrutura de condição `if-elif` para somar +1 caso entre na condição

### Código

```
lista = []  
val = int(input("digite o valor: "))  
while (val != -1):  
    lista.append(val)  
    val = int(input("digite o valor: "))  
print('a lista: ', lista)  
  
print('a quantidade de valores informados é: ')  
print(len(lista))  # quantidade de valores informados  
  
print('a ordem informada foi: ', lista)  
lista.reverse()  
print('em ordem inversa:')  
  
for x in zip(lista):  
    print(x)  
  
soma = sum(lista)  
print('a soma dos valores é: ', soma)  
  
media = soma / len(lista)  
  
acima = 0  
baixo = 0  
  
for valor_media in lista:  
    if valor_media > media:  
        acima += 1  
  elif valor_media < 7:  
        baixo += 1  
  
print('a media é: ', media)  
print(f'Quantidade de valores acima da média: {acima}\nQuantidade de valores abaixo de 7: {baixo}')
```

### Resultado

Após inserir os valores 5, 6, 1, 8 e 10, o sistema gera esse seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]